# How to delete 30 days older files from a directory in Python databricks

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a files in directory with name model/year(current year)/month(current month)/date(current date)
`Example model/2023/01/24/mm.parquet, model/25/02/1998/mm.parquet`.

so there are dozens of file there on my directory so i want to delete files which is 30 days older. For example if latest file is of today's date 2023/03/01 then the file which is 30 days older i.e 2023/02/01 should be deleted.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
# now=str(datetime.now().date())
import pandas as pd
def cleanup_model_output( days_to_keep ):
    path='C://Users/anubhav.sharma02/Downloads/21-01-1998.xlsx'
    date_of_file= int(path.split('/')[-1][0:2])
    now=str(datetime.now().date())
    a=int(now.split(',')[0][-2:])
    subtract=abs(a-date_of_file)
    if subtract > days_to_keep:
        os.remove('C://Users/anubhav.sharma02/Downloads/21-01-1998.xlsx')
```

Can anyone help me on this? i am not able to make a logic

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I split the folder names and take the date/ month and try to subtract 30 from that.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: @KlausD. can you please look at the code

Answer (score 0):

Considering the requirement of deleting file which depends on file path (`root/year/month/date/file.parquet`).
Based on your code, I understand that you are able to access local files from databricks and want to delete the local files.

I did the same with files from Storage account. You can try the same code which also works for you.

First, I have mounted the Storage account to my container `data`. This is my folder structure.

```
data
    2023
        02
            25
                mycsv21columns.csv
            26
                csv26.csv
                mycsv2.csv
            27
                csv27.csv
            28
                csv28.csv
        03
            01
                csv01.csv
            02
                csv02.csv
```

Now, I will delete the files inside folder `25`(taken example for more than last 6 days).

First get all the files list using the below code:

```
import os
all_paths=[]
import glob
for file in glob.iglob("/dbfs/mnt/data/2023/**/*.csv",recursive=True):
    all_paths.append(file)
print("all paths : ",all_paths)
```

[image]

Now, build required files paths array using dates like below as per your requirement.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.now()                                              
l=["/dbfs/mnt/data/"+(start-timedelta(days=day)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")+"/*.csv" for day in range(1, 6)]
print("To list all files inside it: ",l)
req_paths=[]
for i in l:
    for j in glob.iglob(i):
        req_paths.append(j)
print("\nRequired paths: ",req_paths)
```

[image]

Now, based on the above two lists, remove the files which are in `all_paths` and not in `req_paths` like below.

```
for i in all_paths:
    if i not in req_paths:
        os.remove(i)
```

**Result:**

[image]